# How to pass matrix by reference or get the return value of function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 1 x 118 matrix called `current_load` that I need to update periodically. This matrix resides in the main workspace of Matlab (as shown in the code bellow).

```
current_loads = zeros(1, 118); 
for col=1:118
    current_loads(1,col)=10; %// Initially give all nodes a current load of 10    
end
recursive_remove(current_loads); %calling function
```

This matrix will be passed to a function call `recursive_remove` (*shown bellow*).

```
function updater = recursive_remove( current_load )
     current_load(1,3) = 2.6; %// This update can't be seen from main ??
     %this function will be called recursively later
end
```

But whatever updates I do to this `current_load` matrix from the function, it will not get updated since I don't know how to pass it by reference.

I am new to Matlab. I would greatly appreciate if you can show with an example how to handle this

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: "How to pass parameter by reference in Matlab"
You can solve your problem passing your arguments by reference**

You need a [handle class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html)

> Handle Classes
>
> Objects that share references with other objects

this is, create a file called HandleObject.m with this code:

```
classdef HandleObject < handle
   properties
      Object=[];
   end

   methods
      function obj=HandleObject(receivedObject)
         obj.Object=receivedObject;
      end
   end
end
```

Then you can do something like this

```
Object = HandleObject(your matrix)
yourFunction(Object)
```

And inside your function

```
function yourFunction(myObject)
    myObject.object = new matrix;
end
```

With that you can achieve some kind of pass by reference and avoid getting a lot of copies trought your program.

Comment: I was thinking exactly about that when I saw the title of the question, only to see that finally it wasn't actually the question. Nice answer anyway !

Comment: Why it wasn't?, he wanted to change the value of the matrix inside of a function.

Comment: Well, in fairness the OP hinted in comment that that's what he was looking for. But from what I understand, he real title of the question should be more like "how to return a result from a function". This has little to do with how to **pass** argument to the function but rather how to return them. Anyway, I think your answer deserve to stay, but to make it more understandable now, may be you should edit it and add on top that you were initially answering "How to pass parameter by reference in Matlab"

Comment: the real title of the question should be "please solve my problem", anything who make the code of the guy code works would be fine for him. anyway thanks ;) I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The output of the function recursive_remove hasn't been defined and so you ouput can't be used anywhere else.

In matlab you define outputs of functions with square brackets as below.

`function [ output1, output2 ] = recursive_remove( input1, input2 )`

The outputs can now be passed into other [MATLAB docs - functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

When calling the function in the example above in a different function as you did in your first bit of code you would call it as shown:

```
current_loads = zeros(1, 118); 
for col=1:118
    current_loads(1,col)=10; %Initially give all nodes a current load of 10    
end
[ output1, output2 ] = recursive_remove( input1, input2 ); %calling function
```

With this syntax you can take `output1` and call it in the input of your next function `recursive_remover`

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me with an example code. It's very clear now

Comment: just need to clear that this answer is pass by value, not pass by reference.

Comment: thanks actually i always confuse the two just found this and it explained it really well, doubt i'll forget it now... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value